# Export data content to other db (oracle)

Tags: 2010, migrate

I want to migrate sharepoint 2010 DMS (document management system) to Wordpress and have some problem...

How i can export sharepoint content db to Oracle? (items with attached files (doc,pdf, etc), versioning...)
Some utils (https://sharepointdatabaseexplorer.codeplex.com)?

Anyway, does anybody have experience with the migrate Sharepoint to other platform, db?